# On premise transactional email w/ inbound parse

Tags: email, postfix, email-server

I have an application that requires a transactional mail server that also supports inbound mail parsing. The application was previously setup to use Sendgrid for this using their inbound parse API (receives mail and POSTs to webhook endpoint on our application), but a fully on-premise solution is needed in this case.

Does any open source or commercial software exist that will meet these requirements? Most of the transactional mail software I have found either don't have an on-premise option or don't support inbound mail parse.

If there is no such all-in-one solution, is there software that will handle the inbound parse side of things? The only solution I have found so far is using postfix with shell scripts to parse and POST the email contents.

Comment: POSTing incoming mail is a few lines of code and any developer - or even any sysadmin - who understands his local mailer ought to be able to get that up and running in an afternoon.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect there are not a lot of tools as the parse rules are likely to be application specific.  However,  I work with a number of tools that do accept requests from email.  Most poll a mailbox and parse the messages they find.

For simple processing tools like `procmail` allow parsing, filtering and transformation of messages. `procmail` sas the ability to pass the message off to a program for processing.  I use this to handle DMARC reports and load them into a database.  I've also used it to parse, log and remail requests for delivery to a pager.  In my case I use `exim4`, but postfix should be able to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Hurricane MTA Server will be able to do what you want so long as you don't mind a little .Net coding of a plugin.  Here at SocketLabs we are using it for that exact same purpose to support the inbound service for our cloud email services. If this is something you want to explore, please reach out to us and we will help.

Here is a link to the Hurricane MTA Server information, but parsing is not listed as a feature but can be accomplished with a custom plugin as mentioned above.  https://www.socketlabs.com/on-premise-options/hurricane-mta-server/

Good luck with your project.